# Why is the result of sum doubled in this simple query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
mysql> create table a (
    -> id varchar(10),
    -> val int
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> create table b (
    -> id varchar(10),
    -> val int
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into a values ('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3);

mysql> insert into b values ('a', 4), ('a', 5), ('b', 6), ('b', 7), ('c', 8), ('c', 9);

mysql> select a.id, sum(a.val), sum(b.val) from a inner join b on a.id = b.id group by a.id;
+------+------------+------------+
| id   | sum(a.val) | sum(b.val) |
+------+------------+------------+
| a    |          2 |          9 |
| b    |          4 |         13 |
| c    |          6 |         17 |
+------+------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

My expected result was for `sum(a.val)` to present 1, 2 and 3, `sum(b.val)` to present 9, 13 and 17.

How should I rewrite the query to get the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to the `JOIN` with the other table.

If you just run the simple query with the JOINS but without the `SUM`, you will see that the records in Table A are being doubled, because you `INNER JOIN` with TABLE B.

```
A.ID    A.val    B.val
 a       1        4
 a       1        5
 b       2        6
 b       2        7
 c       3        8
 c       3        9
```

In order to get the expected result, you will have to query like this:

```
SELECT 
    A.ID, 
    A.VAL 'A Sum', 
    B.VAL 'B Sum'
FROM
(SELECT ID, SUM(VAL) AS 'VAL' FROM A GROUP BY ID) A INNER JOIN
(SELECT ID, SUM(VAL) AS 'VAL' FROM B GROUP BY ID) B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3dac3/6) with how this query works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the result of the join query before doing the group by and sum:

```
a.id    a.val    b.val
----    -----    -----
a       1        4
a       1        5
b       2        6
b       2        7
c       3        8
c       3        9
```

As you see here, the sum(a.val) for all rows with a.id='a' will give you 2 since there are 2 rows.  So the results, are [2, 4, 6], not [1, 2, 3].